# Unity3d admob unclickable

Tags: c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine, admob

I try to add ads to my game. I use unity 4.3.0f4 with [this](https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin) plugin. Everything works good, but when I try to click advertisment, nothing happens. Advertisment should become darker, but it look the same. I found that in my manifest I should change `unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik` to true, but in my manifest it is true. I even create new project, but it still is unclickable. What should I do to make my ads clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Unity V4.3.4f1

add

```
 <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

inside

```
"com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" activity
```

not

```
UnityPlayerProxyActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

With Unity 4.3, you'll need to add

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

inside the `UnityPlayerProxyActivity` activity.